# OpenCV BFMatcher - how does it classify?

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, brute-force

I'm using the OpenCV ORB method to detect objects in a video stream. My question is to how exactly BFMatcher achieves this?

As far as I'm aware the FlannBasedMatcher uses a KD Tree to classify the objects and that this method will be faster than BFMatcher but the matches may not necessarily be the best.

Comment: As the name suggests, Brute-Force matcher goes through the entire list of descriptor entries to find a match. These are not classifiers really.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of using **BFMatcher** is to match keypoint descriptors.

The simplest method of matching descriptors is searching for the most similar descriptor in different images. This is done by the **BFMatcher::match** method which finds the best match for each descriptor from a query image.

There are other methods such as **BFMatcher::knnMatch** and **BFMatcher::radiusMatch** that are more complex but must be used in certain applications.

*BFMatcher OpenCV docs:* http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#descriptormatcher-match